# Why doesn't this mod_rewrite rule work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

When I try to use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articleID/([^/]*)$ /viewArticle.php?articleID=$1 [L]
```

It sends me to a 404 page.

I am not well-versed in how to use an htaccess, so I most likely did something wrong. I generated it with a tool at generateit.net

I'm trying to access http://majornoob.com/devel/testdesign/articleID/5 which would equal http://majornoob.com/devel/testdesign/viewArticle.php?articleID=5

Comment: it would be nice if you added details/samples on urls that you want to work with your mod_rewrite rule

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry -- what can I add to the post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a RewriteBase:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Also make sure that your server accept htaccess files. Does the Server configure contains a AllowOverride all statment in your Directory Directive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this didn't work. I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Directory Directive, what's that? I checked with HostGator support and they said they do accept htaccess files and mod_rewrite does work.

Comment: In that case you can skip that part... Does adding a /? after the ^ work for you?

Comment: No, however I added \.html in front of the first $ and it works now, but it appears it has stripped all of my styles, any clue why?

Comment: How does you include your styles? You have to add a ../ prefix. Due the rewrite the styles are in an upper Directory.

Comment: I've added up to four ../, it still isn't working. I've tried to load the page each time.

Comment: Solved via referencing them using full path.

Answer (score 0):

With the path, it should work:

```
RewriteRule articleID/([^/]*)$ /devel/testdesign/viewArticle.php?articleID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Though my css still get's stripped. Any idea why?